# How to reset/bypass iphone password after restarting iPhone

Tags: iphone, usb, password

Last night I changed my iPhone's password, but now I've forgotten what it was, and since then it ran out of power so now it's at Before First Unlock mode.

So now I can't access my iPhone, and I've already burnt through several chances trying to get in (last i saw it was at the 'try again after 5 minutes').

I have 'Disabled USB accessories after an hour' active, so i can't connect to it via my MacBook either to backup or reset password through either iTunes or some other third-party application, unless there is a way to bypass that.

If there is any solution to my predicament without resetting the iPhone i'd like to know. The last update was many, many months ago and i'd rather not lose all that data.

While I do remember my AppleID password, it requires 2FA to login, meaning I can't really access it without my phone. I do have an older iPhone that I might be able to use but I'd rather not use it if I can avoid doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also https://support.apple.com/HT204306 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274942/i-have-an-iphone-6-and-forgot-my-passcode https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188892/restore-my-ipad https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336074/how-do-i-unlock-my-ipad If all that fails, take it, with proof of purchase, to an Apple Store.

Comment: Re 2FA - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291055/got-a-new-iphone-where-am-i-supposed-to-receive-the-verification-code